# Global Angular CLI failing to upgrade

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Our current global version of angular is 12.2.7 and we are trying to upgrade to the latest global version.

[image]

We have run the following the steps :-

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and then

```
ng v
```

Only to be presented with the exact same CLI version

We have also tried

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Is there anything more fundamental that we need to do?

Comment: Do you use a custom registry ? (defined in your `~/.npmrc`)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler not that im aware of?  we are trying to upgrade the global frame work, but nothing seems to update it...